# How to use onActivityResult in recyclerview adapter in android?

Tags: android-camera, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I am trying to use onActivityResult in my RecyclerViewAdapter.I have search OnActivityResult there is no option and also StartActivityResult  get the error.Please anyone help me.

Comment: Handle it in your Activity (or Fragment, whichever you're using to `startActivityForResult` from)

Comment: ok i will try and how to use onActivityResult in Recyclerview adapter.